# Return time difference as integer

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a script that calculates time difference between today and first post. I need to have a condition where a certain thing happens if result of a calculation based on that time difference is a whole number. When I echo end result of a calculation it shows a whole number. But when I check if it is an integer- nothing happens.

I' tracked down the problem to the time difference not being recognized as an integer, despite being a whole number.

```
$todays_date = current_time('d-m-Y'); 
//I will skip WP post loop to save space. It works.
$first_date = get_the_date( 'd-m-Y' );
$count = 3;
$date_diff = strtotime($todays_date) - strtotime($first_date);
$date_diff_val = abs(round($date_diff/86400));
if ($date_diff_val/$count > 1) {
$display_date2 = ($date_diff_val-1)/$count;
if (is_int($display_date2)) {
        echo 'works';
    }
}
```

I've tried substituting `$date_diff_val` for number `10` and it worked. So, clearly the issue is with `$date_diff_val`, but I can not figure out what is it exactly.

Comment: Do you want to try add `echo` and print out the `$date_diff_val`? maybe its not an int but its a float?

Comment: It's very likely a float, and therefor not an integer - still a numeric value, but not integer.

Comment: You round it, but that does not make it an integer `abs(round($date_diff/86400));`. Since its rounded, you can now typecast it, `(int)abs(round($date_diff/86400));`

Comment: @aljx0409 I did. Float or not- doesn't work.

Comment: @Qirel Yep, That's it. Works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies with

```
abs(round($date_diff/86400))
```

This will round and take the absolute value of something that may be a float. However, `round()` returns a floating-value, even if it was rounded to a whole number. `abs()` returns of the same type (so if it got a float, it returns a float). You can typecast the value to integer, by doing

```php
$date_diff_val = (int)abs(round($date_diff / 86400));
```

- [PHP manual on `round()`](https://php.net/round)
- [PHP manual on `abs()`](https://php.net/abs)
- [Live demo showing the resulting float](https://3v4l.org/CQHoi) / [showing the typecasting](https://3v4l.org/cANI3)